# load google map without using callback method

Tags: javascript, google-maps

i have multiple google map instances on my website,now there are two different google map on a same page, what happens is the first one works and other doesn't now i know the logical issue let me show you my code first

```
<script>
    function initMap() {
        var myLatLng = {lat: 43.6222102, lng:-79.6694881};

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 15,
            center: myLatLng
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map,
        });
    }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=my_key&callback=initMap"
        async defer></script>
```

now as i defined a callback method it always initializes the method named **initMap** whereas what i want to do is there can be multiple google maps lets suppose **initMap2** how can i load them without **callback** method?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To load the map without a callback, load the API synchronously/inline (without the `async defer`), then call your initMap function on the load event.

(**Note:** FYI: Google changed all their examples to using asynchronous loading to improve the load times)

(**Note2:** Google has added a ["sample" to their documentation describing synchronous loading](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-sync))

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/3Lvtnx7x/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var myLatLng = {
    lat: 43.6222102,
    lng: -79.6694881
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 15,
    center: myLatLng
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<!-- added 1/21/2023 to prevent:
Loading the Google Maps JavaScript API without a callback is not supported: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/url-params#required_parameters
-->
<script>
function dummy() {}
window.dummy=dummy;
</script>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=dummy"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```