# Google MAP API Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript

I have an error in my console, when I use the google map API.
Here is my html code:

```
<body>
      <div id="map"></div>
      <div id="panorama"></div>
 
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=******&callback=init"
        async defer></script>
</body>
```

I have one index.js where I initialize my map:

```
import {
    initMap
} from './map'
import {
    buildAllDreams
} from './dream'

function init() {
    initMap();
    buildAllDreams();
}

window.init = init;
```

and one map.js where I create my function:

```
let map;
let panorama;
const panoramaElement = document.querySelector("#panorama");
const resetMapButton = document.querySelector("#reset-map");
const backToMapButton = document.querySelector("#back-to-map");


function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {
            lat: 8.063636,
            lng: 98.458580
        },
        zoom: 2,
        streetViewControl: false
    });

    panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
        document.getElementById('panorama'), {
            position: {
                lat: 8.0571641,
                lng: 98.4585744
            },
            pov: {
                heading: 34,
                pitch: 10
            }
        });
}

export {
    initMap,
};
```

I have this error in my console:

Uncaught (in promise)
ld {message: "init is not a function", name: "InvalidValueError", stack: "Error↵    at new ld ([https://maps.googleapis.com/*******&callback=init:141:124"}](https://maps.googleapis.com/*******&callback=init:141:124%22%7D)

I don't know what's going on
Can you help me please

the complete error in my console:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgHXj.png)

Comment: What is the full error?

Comment: Remove the `&callback=init` part from your `script` tag

Comment: I added a descriptive image of the complete error in my message

Comment: This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44659884/load-google-map-without-using-callback-method

Comment: thanks for your help, when I delete the call back init, as well as the Async defer I no longer have the error, but the card still does not appear

Comment: Yes so you need to call the init function yourself now, refer the above link for an answer

Comment: Ok thanks for your help, I succeeded with your help provided :)